# Adding light box to images

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, magnific-popup

I have no experience with CSS and JQuery. Therefore I am lost with implementing Magnific Popup with my app. I am using the https://github.com/joshuajansen/magnific-popup-rails. The code I insert in the view is showing on the page itself. I followed what's on the github and then added code to the view.

```
<h1><%= @user.username %></h1>

<div class="parent-container">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image'
  });   
});

<% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)), photo.image_url%>

</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You need to add tag `<script type="text/javascript">` and then the code. Close tag at the end. Check Josh's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My knowledge of ruby on rails is rather limited, but I am pretty sure you need to include your javascript in a script tag like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'image'
        });   
    });
</script>

<div class="parent-container">
    <% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)), photo.image_url%>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking <%= javascript_include_tag "PATH HERE" %>. That was fairly simple and easy.

Answer (score 1):

Josh Mein's answer is correct, but to stay true to w3c standards and have the javascript in the head, you might also consider:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type='text/javsacript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image'
      });   
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

... and then in your layout make sure you have `<%= yield :head %>` in the head section